# JQuery get file by post in new window and error in current

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a Action in controller, that return a file.
And I download this file in new tab

```
 window.location = MyUrl + "?" + $.param(data);
```

But if I throw an exception in action - I get an json error message in new tab. But I want to get and show error message in current tab, but download file only in new.
How can I do it?